# Gradle Docker Fail with ERROR: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount145682111/build/libs: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, gradle

I am creating simple spring boot application named channelling and trying to build docker image using gradle.
Here is my build.gradle script

```
plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
   id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.25.0'
}

docker {
   name "${project.name}:${project.version}"
   files 'channeling.jar'
   tag 'DockerHub', "test-usr/test:${project.version}"
}
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

And this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} channeling.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/channeling.jar"]
```

Once I trying to build image using bellow command, It works fine.

```
docker build -t springio/test .
```

But when I run `gradle docker`
It gives bellow error message.

```
#6 [2/2] COPY build/libs/*.jar channeling.jar
#6 sha256:73a6a8447f65c5bb42b12cceabb3dfa40d4f67e73c569b617331cfdcb9a6a963
#6 ERROR: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount145682111/build/libs: no such file or directory
------
> [2/2] COPY build/libs/*.jar channeling.jar:
------
lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount145682111/build/libs: no such file or directory
> Task :channel:docker FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
```

Project structure is like bellow.

[image]

I am using bellow gradle and docker versions.

```
gradle : 6.8
docker : 20.10.2
```

I searched this issue online but didn't find the solution. Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I fixed it by avoiding using 'docker' function in Gradle build. Instead I added the following to build.gradle.kts:

```
configure<com.palantir.gradle.docker.DockerExtension> {
   dependsOn(tasks.findByPath("build"))
   name = "${project.name}:${version}"
   files("build/libs/${project.name}-${version}.jar")
   buildArgs(mapOf("JAR_FILE" to "${project.name}-${version}.jar"))
}
```

Also, make sure you put dependsOn function, as it has to execute after build.